# How to fetch image url from firebase Data Storage?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am using this code below and all I get instead of URL is `com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@a0a540`. How can I get the actual URL?

```
 filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful()){
            mImageStorage.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
               @Override
               public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                   Uri downloadUri = filePath.getMetadata().getDownloadUrl();
                   generatedFilePath = downloadUri.toString();
                    String downlaodURL = uri.toString();

                    (mUserDatabase.child("image").setValue(downlaodURL).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            mUploadImage.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,"image uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,"image URL not set",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
               }
           });
        }
        else{
            mUploadImage.hide();
            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,"Error uploading image",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: explain your problem in this manner: 1. Your workflow 2. how you achieve what you intended to be 3. What goes wrong

Comment: Is filePath an instance of StorageReference? 

           StorageReference filePath =
                    FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
                            .getReference(mFirebaseUser.getUid())
                            .child("profile/");

before calling the filePath.putFile(.....)

Comment: Your code looks fine. onSuccess is returning the Uri which you are using to get the url and setting it in your db. Can you tell exactly where you are getting the toString value ?

Comment: i am trying to get URL in downloadURL variable ... but it is giving me wrong string ... something like com.google.gms...

Comment: @AngusTay  1) everything working with good flow.
2)i am trying to get string URL .. which i am getting wrong ..

Comment: Which one `downloadUri` or `downlaodURL` is printing `com.google.gms...`?

Comment: downloadURL (string) is printing com.google.gms.... @AlexMamo